# Index() count in python

Tags: python

I am trying to count the Index value to get the how many server names are repating in the output.

But I want the output to be like server name and their occurrences/count

Server 1,2 server2,3 server3 ,2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import subprocess
from collections import Counter

cmd="sudo /opt/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpdbjobs|egrep -v 'Done|Incomplete|Waiting-to-Retry|Cleanup|Catalog|Cleaning|Restore'"
def jobs_m_severcount():
        m_server = subprocess.Popen((cmd),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,encoding="utf-8")
        for line in m_server.stdout.readlines():
                line=line.lstrip()
                if not line.startswith('JobID'):
                        line=line.split()
                        counts=line[6]
                        print(counts)
jobs_m_severcount()

'''
output:

server1
server2
server1
server2
server3
server2
server3
```

Comment: Why did you import `Counter` and didn't use it?

Comment: I am new to python. saw online counters will work but not sure how make use of them in my case

Answer (score 1):

First append them to list and then make list from it that has no duplicates. then use it to count items from first list

```
servers = []
def jobs_m_severcount():
        m_server = subprocess.Popen((cmd),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,encoding="utf-8")
        for line in m_server.stdout.readlines():
                line=line.lstrip()
                if not line.startswith('JobID'):
                        line=line.split()
                        counts=line[6]
                        print(counts)
                        servers.append(counts)

jobs_m_severcount()


# This deletes duplicates since set cant have two same items
names = list(set(servers))

# Count occurance of name from list
for i in(names):
    print(f"{i} = {servers.count(i)}")
```

Comment: Below is the out put .your suggestion worked to get the count of servers.If I want to get the count of Active jobs which is 7 from the below output.(Active =7).Sorry how modify my above script

JobID Type State Policy Schedule Client Server name
4256780 Backup Active windows weekly client1 sever1
4255364 Backup Active windows weekly client2 server2
4255362 Backup Active windows weekly client3 server2
4255361 Backup Active UNIX weekly client4 server2
4255351 Backup Active UNIX weekly client5 sever1
4255348 Backup Active UNIX - client6 sever1
4255347 Backup Active UNIX - client7 sever1

Comment: I assume that you can get num of jobs by counting "printed rows" so you can use jobs=len(servers)

Comment: Or  you can straight print it: print(f"Active = {len(servers)}")